Why can't I take inputs , Here's the code
I'm currently at a beginner phase and I was trying to implement MVVM architecture but I can;t seem to find the issue.
There are Three Files:

Main Activity
UnitConverterScreen
UnitModel
UnitViewModel

Problem:
There's an OutlinedTextField in which when a value is Enterred , it then calls the calculation function using ViewModel, it then converts the enterred value to the value we want to convert, for the conversion ,There are two dropdowns, One Tells current values Unit and Another is to know to which we need to get the conversion in. This is what was suppose to Happen but I'm not able to enter any value in the outlined text field or change Units from the dropdown, So, ultimately no result or change on the App screen.
Main - Activity
package com.bank.unitconverter

import android.graphics.Paint.Align
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowDropDown
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.ArrowDropDown
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenu
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.bank.unitconverter.ui.theme.UnitConverterTheme
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            val viewModel:UnitViewModel by viewModels()
            UnitConverterTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    UnitConverterScreen(viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


UnitModel
package com.bank.unitconverter

import kotlin.math.roundToInt

data class UnitModel(
    var inputValue: String,
    var inputUnit: String,
    var outputValue: String,
    var outputUnit: String,
    var iExpanded: Boolean,
    var oExpanded: Boolean,
    var conversionFactor:Double,
    var oconversionFactor:Double
)

class UnitRepository{
    private var _data = UnitModel(
        "",
        "Meters",
        "",
        "Meters",
        false,
        false,
        1.00,
        1.00)

    fun getData() = _data

    fun calculateUnit(){
        val inputValueDouble = _data.inputValue.toDoubleOrNull()?:0.00
        val result = (inputValueDouble * _data.conversionFactor*100.0/_data.oconversionFactor).roundToInt()/100.0
        _data.outputValue = result.toString()
    }

}

UnitViewModel
package com.bank.unitconverter

import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel


class UnitViewModel:ViewModel(){
    private val _repository: UnitRepository = UnitRepository()
    private var _inputValue =  mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().inputValue)
    private var _OutputValue = mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().outputValue)
    private var _inputUnit = mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().inputUnit)
    private var _OutputUnit = mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().outputUnit)
    private var _iExpanded = mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().iExpanded)
    private var _oExpanded = mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().oExpanded)
    private var _conversionFactor = mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().conversionFactor)
    private var _oconversionFactor = mutableStateOf(_repository.getData().oconversionFactor)

    var inputValue:MutableState<String> = _inputValue
    val outputValue:MutableState<String> = _OutputValue
    val inputUnit:MutableState<String> = _inputUnit
    val outputUnit:MutableState<String> = _OutputUnit
    val iExpanded:MutableState<Boolean> = _iExpanded
    val oExpanded:MutableState<Boolean> = _oExpanded
    val conversionFactor:MutableState<Double> = _conversionFactor
    val oconversionFactor:MutableState<Double> = _oconversionFactor


    fun calculation(){
        _repository.calculateUnit()

        _inputValue.value = _repository.getData().inputValue
        _OutputValue.value = _repository.getData().outputValue
        _inputUnit.value = _repository.getData().inputUnit
        _OutputUnit.value = _repository.getData().outputUnit
        _iExpanded.value = _repository.getData().iExpanded
        _oExpanded.value = _repository.getData().oExpanded
        _conversionFactor.value = _repository.getData().conversionFactor
        _oconversionFactor.value = _repository.getData().oconversionFactor
    }
}

UnitConverterScreen
package com.bank.unitconverter

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowDropDown
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenu
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp

@Composable
fun UnitConverterScreen(viewModel: UnitViewModel){

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        Text("Unit Converter", style = TextStyle(
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
            fontSize = 30.sp,
            color = Color.Black
        )
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(value = viewModel.inputValue.value, onValueChange = {
            viewModel.inputValue.value = it
            viewModel.calculation()
        }, label = { Text("Enter a Value") })

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Row {
            Box{
                Button(onClick = {
                    viewModel.iExpanded.value = true
                }) {
                    Text(viewModel.inputUnit.value)
                    Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "Arrow Down")
                }
                DropdownMenu(expanded = viewModel.iExpanded.value, onDismissRequest = { viewModel.iExpanded.value = false}) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Centimeter") },
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.iExpanded.value = false
                            viewModel.inputUnit.value = "Centimeters"
                            viewModel.conversionFactor.value = 0.01
                            viewModel.calculation()
                        })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Meter") },
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.iExpanded.value = false
                            viewModel.inputUnit.value = "Meters"
                            viewModel.conversionFactor.value = 1.0
                            viewModel.calculation()
                        })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Kilometer") },
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.iExpanded.value = false
                            viewModel.inputUnit.value = "Kilometers"
                            viewModel.conversionFactor.value = 1000.0
                            viewModel.calculation()
                        })
                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(30.dp))
            Box{
                Button(onClick = {
                    viewModel.oExpanded.value = true
                }) {
                    Text(viewModel.outputUnit.value)
                    Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "Arrow Down")
                }
                DropdownMenu(expanded = viewModel.oExpanded.value, onDismissRequest = { viewModel.oExpanded.value = false }) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Centimeter") },
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.oExpanded.value = false
                            viewModel.outputUnit.value = "Centimeters"
                            viewModel.oconversionFactor.value = 0.01
                            viewModel.calculation()
                        })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Meter") },
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.oExpanded.value = false
                            viewModel.outputUnit.value = "Meters"
                            viewModel.oconversionFactor.value = 1.0
                            viewModel.calculation()
                        })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Kilometer") },
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.oExpanded.value = false
                            viewModel.outputUnit.value = "Kilometers"
                            viewModel.oconversionFactor.value = 1000.0
                            viewModel.calculation()
                        })
                }

            }

        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        Text("Result: ${viewModel.outputValue.value} ${viewModel.outputUnit.value} ", style = TextStyle(
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            color = Color.Blue
        )
        )
    }

}

I was Hoping that I'll be able to input text in the Outlined Text Field, and eventually Calculation will take place.....But Either of the things are not happening.

What IS happening?  You haven't told us the real problem.

@TimRoberts, There's an OutlinedTextField in which when a value is Enterred , it then calls the calculation function using ViewModel, it then converts the enterred value to the value we want to convert, for the conversion ,There are two dropdowns, One Tells current values Unit and Another is to know to which we need to get the conversion. This is what was suppose to Happen but I'm not able to enter any value in the outlined text field or change Units from the dropdown, So, ultimately no result or change on the App screen.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There's a lot of debugging to be done.  You need to do some debug prints to make sure the values are getting sent from the OutlinedTextField to the viewmodel into the repository.
